# Show Button in Other Scene Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to ask something, can we load (show) button in difference scene (scene B) from button I (clicked) in my main scene (scene A), and scene change to scene B,

Thanks before,

Comment: I don't think you can make changes to a scene that isn't active but I may be wrong. But what you can do is keep track of the buttons that were pressed in Scene A, then onload of Scene B, create those buttons. Or if the buttons are always in the same place, you could create them beforehand, and use `.SetActive(true/false)` on the buttons that were pressed on the previous scene, to make them visible/hidden

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how you can show a button in one scene (A) then click a button in (A) then go to a new scene (B), you can do this using [SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html).

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; 

// assign your button's onclick to be this function
public void LoadNewScene()
{
     SceneManagement.LoadScene("YOUR_SCENE_NAME_HERE");
}
```

Make sure to add the scene you want to load to your build settings. Without it being added, it will not be able to load it. [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) is a more detailed page about LoadScene.